# Ionic + Firebase Facebook Login in Production

Tags: xcode, facebook, oauth, firebase, ionic-framework

I have followed the official tutorial for setting up Facebook login using Firebase and Ionic from the Firebase website. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ionic/guide.html#section-user-authentication

When I run my app via the command line using the Ionic CLI, everything works.

`ionic run ios --device`

But, when I try to build the app in Xcode and connect with Facebook the redirect never happens.  I've tried to find out more via the logs but I'm having a tough time having any of my `console.log` calls show up in the Xcode debugger window.

Here is what shows up in the debugger window currently

```
2015-10-15 13:13:26.237 blaze[4112:1657211] Apache Cordova native platform version 3.7.0 is starting.
2015-10-15 13:13:26.238 blaze[4112:1657211] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2015-10-15 13:13:26.242 blaze[4112:1657211] Unlimited access to network resources
2015-10-15 13:13:26.394 blaze[4112:1657211] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 0.240982ms
2015-10-15 13:13:26.394 blaze[4112:1657211] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 0.539005ms
2015-10-15 13:13:26.689 blaze[4112:1657211] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2015-10-15 13:13:27.352 blaze[4112:1657211] Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A2FDC031-A62A-46AA-BE31-B921049841AC/blaze.app/www/index.html#/login
2015-10-15 13:13:36.596 blaze[4112:1657211] Setting the WebView's frame to {{0, 0}, {375, 623}}
2015-10-15 13:13:36.607 blaze[4112:1657211] THREAD WARNING: ['InAppBrowser'] took '74.574951' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

Note - I've been able to get the facebook login to work perviously from building it in Xcode, but since the ios9 upgrade it doesn't work.  But, it has never worked when I've tried to package my app and submit it for testing to the App store.  So, I'm wondering if there are different setting for prod/dev for Firebase Facebook auth.

**Facebook Dev Oauth Setup**
[image: facebook dev oauth setup]

**Firebase Settings for Facebook (urls match)**
[image: firebase auth settings]

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find out more info from using the debugger in Safari.  Turns out the facebook auth is working fine and the data is getting loaded from Firebase correctly.  The issue is that `ng-include` for partials is not working properly in ios.